# Connection closed by target host before receiving the response

Tags: wso2, connection, wso2-esb

We are getting intermittent failures while connecting to one of the backend system. When we looked at the logs we can see that the connection is getting closed by either wso2/backend. We are unbale to make out where exactly the problem is.? Please find the below logs we get immediately(1-3 millisecond) after sending a request.

WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  Connection closed by target host before receiving the response  Remote Address : backend.system.com/0.0.0.0:443

We are using wso2esb-5.0.0. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here the backend has closed the connection for some reason. You may have to check backend logs and backend loadbalancer logs to find a clue.

Some common cases backends fail like this is are being unable to handle

1. Keepalive
2. Chunking
3. HTTP version (1.1 vs 1.0)

Comment: Thanks for your comments Bee. We have checked with the backend team they are investigating from there side. But they suspect that the problem could be on our end as we are getting 'Connection closed' WARN within 1-3 milliseconds. So just wanted to be sure that nothing wrong from our end. Saying that we also experiencing a similar issue with other backends as well sometimes. 
Is there a way to identify and confirm that nothing is wrong from the wso2-esb system.?

Comment: "Connection closed `by target host`" means the problem is with the backend.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just wanted to check if it's possible to enable additional logs at WSO2-ESB to see that request has sent from our end and then the connection got closed from the backend. 
Any logs that give more information about the request and response over that point of time.

Comment: Since this is a TCP level connection closure, taking a TCP dump will be the easiest way here.